# switching code between debug mode and release mode in java - android

Tags: java, android

I would like to know if anyone has any idea of how to switch code between debug mode and release mode? For example, in C#, there is #debug to differentiate the debugging code. The code within #debug only executes in debug mode.

Thanks for any help in advance.

Comment: By debugging mode, do you mean logging level? I do not think there is corresponding #debug mode in Android.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

According to [this](http://developer.android.com/tools/sdk/tools-notes.html) (revision March 2012) :

> Build
>   Added a feature that allows you to run some code only in debug mode. Builds now generate a class called`BuildConfig`containing a`DEBUG`constant that is automatically set according to your build type.
>   You can check the (`BuildConfig.DEBUG`) constant in your code to run debug-only functions.